# Can I change my hub so I can put disc brakes on the bike

Tags: wheels, cassette, hub, hydraulic-disc-brake

So I have this 2007 Janis XC bike and I’m turning it into a trail bike on a budget. I wanted to know if I could change the hub on the wheel instead of buying a new wheel set so I can install some disc brakes?

The bike frame already has I.S mounts for disc brakes.

Comment: Does the frame and fork already have mounts for disk calipers?

Comment: Changing the hub is the easy part.

Comment: Yes the bike Already has I.S mounts

Answer (score 3):

We have to assume, as you haven't provided a photo, that the frame has the attachment points for disc brakes already -- certain bikes have a provision for rim and disc brakes and yours could be one of them.

It is unlikely that you will find a disc - compatible hub with the same "flange" dimesions as your current ones. This is where the spokes are hooked into the hub, if you don't already know.

Therefore you will need to calculate the correct spoke length for the new hub and order the correct length spokes in order to build the wheel. It is very easy, and often quite cheap, just to buy a complete disc compatible rear wheel either new or used, unless you want the experience of wheelbuilding.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks, so either I would need to buy a new wheel set or buy a new hub and spokes? If you could please provide a wheelset 26 inch disc and front and rear that would be highly valued also. If you could find one onder 200 that’s great too!

Comment: Hi @user53993 . Welcome to Bicycles SE.  We don’t do product recommendations here so you’ll need to do your own searching. Good luck with the upgrade.

Comment: @user53993 if you are in the US go to your local bike shop and tell them what you price goal is and plan in general and I'm sure they will be able to find something that will work for you. Should be able to find a decent double wall disc brake pair for that price.

Answer (score 1):

Having them custom built for around $200 is possible if you reuse your rims and you use inexpensive hubs. Spokes will run about $60 for 100 DT Swiss champion 14g silver. I wouldn't re-use your old spokes anyway given that they're, well, old. Making the wheels yourself can get a bit involved in terms of know-how and tool$.

If you're on a budget, look for wheelmaster wheelsets. They're lower end but they fit your needs and are under $150. They're usually laced with 8-10s freehub. See https://www.modernbike.com/wheel-master-26-x-1.5-mach1-sub-zero-disc-mt2000-wheelset

Stay away from the mechanical caliper/lever sets. Hydraulic isn't much more expensive (~$70).